# Userform Listbox multiselect count to hide/unhide number of other controls

Tags: combobox, count, listbox, hide, userform

I have a listbox populated by a range, where multiselect (1) is enabled. The selected items (maximum of 10) then populate Label.Captions that have adjacent comboboxes and textboxes requiring further info from the user. I am looking for code that counts the number of selections made from the list box (between 1 and 10) and then hides my relative comboboxes and textboxes (again, 1 to 10). So if 4 selections are made in the listbox, only combo/Textboxes 1 to 4 are visible (combo/textboxes 5 to 10 are hidden).

I have some elements of the code I think I need but can't complete the full procedure.

```
For lstbxCount = 1 To 10
  If lstbxCount = 1 Then
    UserForm2.Controls("ComboBox" & lstbxCount).Visible = True
    UserForm2.Controls("TextBox" & lstbxCount).Visible = True
Next intCount
```

But the above, if it worked, I think would only show one combobox with the highest count number and would leave all others hidden. I'm looking for a code that loops from combobox 1 up to the lstbxCount number and shows those, and hides anything higher than the lstbxCount integer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is on the right path however does require a few adjustments to get it working.

Currently as you suspected your code will only show your controls if ListBox item 1 exists.

Below is a code that will show/hide UserForm controls based on the selected ListBox items.

**NOTE:** In my test I created:

1. A UserForm named `UserForm1`
2. A ListBox named `ListBox1`
3. Three Label named `Label1`, `Label2` & `Label3`
4. Three TextBox named `TextBox1`, `TextBox2` & `TextBox3`

The code has been assigned to the ListBox Change event in the UserForm module, so every time a change occurs on the ListBox it will show/hide the relevant controls.

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

Dim i As Long

For i = 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then
        i = i + 1
        Me.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = True
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Visible = True
        i = i - 1
    ElseIf Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = False Then
        i = i + 1
        Me.Controls("Label" & i).Visible = False
        Me.Controls("TextBox" & i).Visible = False
        i = i - 1
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

### Explanation:

The variable `i` represents an integer which I'm using as a counter.

The `For...Next` statement is looping from 0 to the ListBox item count minus 1. This is because the ListBox items have a zero-based index meaning the first item in the listbox is index number 0, the second item is index number 1 etc. So, we loop from 0 (the first listbox item) until the `ListCount` value minus 1.

**NOTE:** To clarify, the ListBox Item Index numbers are Zero-Based (starts at 0) where the `ListCount` property is not (starts at 1). This is also explained a little further on.

`If Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = True Then` uses our counter variable as the index number (starting at 0 and increasing by 1 each time the loop iterates) for each ListBox item to determine if it's selected or not.

If it is either selected or not, `i = i + 1` is used to increase our counter by 1. Once our counter value has increased we can now reference the correct controls to show/hide. 
Once we have done so, we decrease our counter by 1 (`i = i - 1`) as with each loop iteration the value of `i` increases. If we don't decrease `i` before the next loop iteration it we will skip list items which means some items to show/hide controls and some won't.

---

---

To elaborate, let's remove the variable `i` and use the first iteration of the loop as an **example**;

The first iteration would translate to:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()

For 0 To Me.ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    If Me.ListBox1.Selected(0) = True Then
        Me.Controls("Label1").Visible = True
        Me.Controls("TextBox1").Visible = True
    ElseIf Me.ListBox1.Selected(i) = False Then
        Me.Controls("Label1").Visible = False
        Me.Controls("TextBox1").Visible = False
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

I'll leave it to you to adjust the code to suit your variables and reference the correct names of objects/controls.